# Assign public IP address to Hyper-V guest

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using bridge connection to get ip access from guest in Hyper V](https://serverfault.com/questions/352021/using-bridge-connection-to-get-ip-access-from-guest-in-hyper-v)

I have now been trying for nearly 4 days to setup what i would think is the simplest hyperV env.

I have a host 2008r2 server with two public ips.

I have created a guest and can connect to it via hyperV manager.

I want this guest to be on my second public ip and be able to remote desktop to it from outside.

Currently the guest cannot access the internet but it is connected to the host virtual network adaptor.

I installed the routing and remote access role and have set up a private interface on the virtual network connection and a public interface on the physical one with.

I have also configured NAT following these steps http://blog.jim80.net/2010/01/19/setting-up-hyper-v-with-nat/ but this doesnt seem to have any effect at all. All the remote desktop sessions still going to the host.

i have also tried setting up static routes inside the IPv4 of routing and remote access.

I really need to know what the correct method is here as there doesnt seem to be any working simple examples on the web. Do i use NAT or static routes and if so what are the settings I need. Seem unbelievable that this relatively basic use case has so much obscured/duplicated config.

all help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the guest to have exclusive use of your "second" public IP address:

1. Bridge the guest machine's network adapter to your physical network card
2. Remove the 2nd public IP address from the Hyper-V host.
3. Assign the 2nd public IP address to the guest (in the guest OS settings).

You do not need to use RRAS or NAT or any kind of special routing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have bridged the connection but now have no internet on the host. what tcp ipv4 settings do i need in the bridged connection?

Comment: Please verify that you have not created an IP address conflict. For bridged networking to work, the host and guest need to be configured with separate IP addresses.

Comment: how do i configure this? should I specify the ips inside the tcp properties of the network connection? what should the default gateway of the virtual connection be? thanks a lot

Comment: i have internet connection on the host by specifying the public ip and gateway in the bridge connection. Do both connections in the brdge need to have the same details specified with the hosts public ip/gateway? What should the tcp settings be in the guest? thanks a lot for your help. made more progress in last 30 minutes than in 2 days of pulling my hair out.

Comment: Configure the guest machine EXACTLY as if it were a completely separate computer on the same subnet. Different IP address but same gateway, same netmask, and same DNS servers. Make sure that the host is configured to use *only one* of your two public IP addresses so that you can use the second one for your guest. You can verify which public IP addresses the host is using via `ipconfig /all` at the command line.

Comment: i have done that and still have no internet on the guest. The settings are identical except for the ips which are the two separate public IPs. The ip are on different c class's but i dont supposed that matters. When setting up the bridge connection i lose remote desktop connection until i go (via a console) into the tcp properties of the bridge and set both connections to be the public ip of the host. when you did this did you use dchp on either bridge connection or the guest? Thanks for your help

Comment: I have run ipconfig /all and only the single public ip defined in both bridged connections is there.

Comment: For me, I needed to enable IP4 on the bridge.  Before that, the Host and Guest would "fight" for internet - timing out alternately.  .... after doing what you have outlined above...