# Using bridge connection to get ip access from guest in Hyper V

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I want to access the  internet on a dedicated second public ip from the guest.

I have created an internal only network in Hyper-V Manager. 
The virtual network is in a bridged connection to the physical network card on the host.
I have specified the host's public ip in the tcp setting on the host.

What should the TCP setting for the virtual network card on the host be?
What should the TCP setting for the virtual network card on the guest be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign public IP address to Hyper-V guest](http://serverfault.com/questions/351964/assign-public-ip-address-to-hyper-v-guest)

Comment: I don't suppose it crossed your mind that an "Internal Only" network connection would not have access to External computers. And that maybe you need an External network in order to communication with External Computers... I know, tough naming scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I'm extremely confused by your description of the issue.  If the network you created is internal only, then its not getting out no matter what you do (within reason).  If you created that virtual adapter as connecting to the physical adapter and prevented host access, you should just give the machine an appropriate IP for the outside network and be golden.  On the virtual network card you don't adjust the settings at all, just leave it set as MS Virtual Switch.  Perhaps if I'm missing something you can provide a bit more detail on exactly what your attempting to do, what sort of physical adapters you have to work with, how they're hooked up now, and then I can try to get a bit more assistance for you.

Comment: HI steve, when you say "n the virtual network card you don't adjust the settings at all, just leave it set as MS Virtual Switch." do you mean on the host or on the guest?

Comment: In short - once you configure the virtual network, don't touch the host settings.  If you've already changed them, kill the virtual network and recreate it.

I tried to post pics, but I don't have enough rep:
Server side - http://imgur.com/lyItO

Client Side - http://imgur.com/rGLE1

Comment: Thanks,but how do I assign a public ip to the guest so it can be access from outside by remote desktop.

Comment: The same way you modify any other IP address on the guest OS.  At that point the physical adapter might as well be a direct connection to the virtual machine.

Comment: I have deleted the virtual network and am recreating it as you suggest. however if the option to allow the management operating system to share the the network adaptor is not selected I lose my remote desktop window onto the host. will it work if the network adaptor is shared? Thanks for you help.

Comment: OH!  I see what you're doing.

Give the VM 2 adapters.  One adapter is shared with the host and is a connection to your internal network.  The second is not shared with the host and goes to your outside.

This is assuming you're doing a simple setup where you just have the networks isolated from one another and you're not doing something with your internal routing I can't assume safely.

Comment: thanks steve, how do i give the VM a second adaptor. do i create another virtual network? i cant see a way to add more than one adaptor inside hyper v manager?

Comment: In your case - you already have one adapter and it should now be shared with the host.  Leave that alone.  Create a 2nd network in Hyper-V Network Manager, attach it to as type "External" to your adapter that is facing out and do not allow host access.  Then go into the VM and attach that VM to the new virtual network.  You'll wind up with 2 networks, only the internal facing the Host, and the internal and external visible to the guest.  Configure the IPs like they were physical boxes, don't fiddle with the MS virtual network.  That should be it.